javax-validation not working with spring boot 2.7.18
I have project usinf spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE. As part of migration process to spring boot 3, its recommended to first upgrade to the latest available 2.7.x version. So I try with 2.7.18.
<version>2.7.18</version>

When I run 'mvn clean install' , I start getting many compilation errors('cannot find symbol') related to classes in package import javax.validation.
What has changed? And what's the workaround?

Seems 2.7.18 spring strter doesnt contain validation starter. So I added it explicitly, and errors are gone now.
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

